# Spring-Data h2: java.io.FileNotFoundException when testing in maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data, h2

I have an issue with spring in combination with h2. I use a h2 database for my tests but I have a very strange behavior.

My dependencies:

```
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
...
```

I set the jdbc connection-string for my tests to:

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:dataSource

No consider the basic test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class DemoApplicationTests {
  @Test
  public void contextLoads() {
  }
}
```

If I run

> mvn test

in the same directory where my pom is located, everything works fine. But if execute this command in the parent directory

> mvn -f ./xxx/pom.xml test

the test did not work.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
```

How can I run the tests in the parent directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
    mvn -f xxx/pom.xml test

Comment: Can you give me an explanation why this works? Doesn’t denote it the same?

Comment: The ./ syntax indicating present folder is poorly supported in older java, and frequently can cause errors.  One potential cause for this is the use of 1.4 or previous Ant pattern matching use, depending on your maven version and JDK.  The -f parameter without a leading / assumes you are providing a relative path with the default pattern matcher.  In the future just try different variations and it should work.